# What could make a set of the train data more predictive than the whole train data

Tags: classification, training, prediction

I took a sample of my training data and balanced it and then trained my model. The results obtained are more accurate than using the whole set of train data (balanced or imbalanced). My question is: what could explain this result? (the entire set of data does not contain any noise).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Outliers could be an explanation.

Comment: "(the entire set of data does not contain any noise)"  Do you mean no outliers are contained or really no statistical variation occurs?

Comment: @Alex2006, yes i am  talking about outliers

Comment: In data without outliers, you may have a problem of overfitting. The whole data always contain more noise than a subsample which leads to more precise estimates normally countered by the division through the square root of the sample size when constructing error bars of confidence intervals. Does this occurs with any subsample or just a specific one?

Comment: It occurs with a specific one

Comment: Check several other subsamples. If this happens not all the time, it is likely overfitting.

Comment: This is also possible in case of skewed data. Sample that you had opted luckily had equal ratios. If so, try different sub samples as mentioned by @alex2006.

Comment: OK, thanks for the repsonses, my question is if its an overfitting problem, why should i considered it as a problem if my unseen data are well predicted.

Answer (score 1):

In absence of noise and **if the difference of accuracy you observe is significant**, the only reason I see is that, by luck, the distribution of the training data subset happens to be closer to the distribution of your validation data than the distribution of the whole training data.
This should not happen with truly representative validation data (i.e. with training and validation data built by random split of a given dataset).